# SQL Error: Syntax Near "(": syntax error (C++ Interface)

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run an SQLite Query in my C++ program which removes all duplicate records in one of my database tables. However, I keep encountering various syntax errors.

Here's my SQL table:

```
Table Name: spamtrigrams

ID          TRIGRAM       
----------  ----------  
1           Sam's nice ham        
2           Tuesday was cold       
3           Alex stood up
4           Mark passed out      
5           this database is
6           date with a
7           disco stew pot
++10000
```

Here's my C++ code:

```
  sql = "DELETE from spamtrigrams WHERE id in(" \
    "SELECT id from spamtrigrams" \
    "EXCEPT(SELECT min(id);"  \
    "from spamtrigrams," \
    "group by TRIGRAM," \
    "having count(1) > 1," \
    "union all," \
    "SELECT min(id)," \
    "from spamtrigrams," \
    "group by TRIGRAM," \
    "having count(1) = 1));";
ret = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Duplicates Deleted\n");
```

Is anybody able to tell me why this error occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: You are aware you're missing a `}` in your `if`. That's not your error though: just a posting typo.

Comment: Seriously? Want us to count brackets for you?

Comment: The number of brackets seems to match, but I think there are to many commas. Maybe SQLite is different, but IIRC, there's normally no comma before FROM, GROUP or HAVING. Oh, and the ";" after the third line is definitely wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. Ask the question in terms of SQL _only_, as it is a query syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some spaces and have extra characters here and there:

```
sql = "DELETE from spamtrigrams WHERE id in(" \
"SELECT id from spamtrigrams" \ // <<= Here's a missing space
"EXCEPT(SELECT min(id);"  \     // <<= Here's an extra semicolon
"from spamtrigrams," \          // <<= Here's an extra comma
"group by TRIGRAM," \           // <<= Here's an extra comma
"having count(1) > 1," \        // <<= Here's an extra comma
"union all," \                  // <<= Here's an extra comma
"SELECT min(id)," \             // <<= Here's an extra comma
"from spamtrigrams," \          // <<= Here's an extra comma
"group by TRIGRAM," \           // <<= Here's an extra comma
"having count(1) = 1));";
```

In C++, when you put two string literals together, separated only by white space, the compiler treats them as a single literal. Therefore, it's OK to drop backslashes at the end of each line (or drop double quotes at the end of each line, if you prefer it like that).

Comment: I'm really not getting this - I can't get it to run past the first line, it doesn't seem to like the first '(' ...?

Answer (score 1):

dont know if this is your (only) problem, or, if this is a typo in posting the question, but you have redundant `;` in `"EXCEPT(SELECT min(id);"`

this is in addition to the missing spaces mentioned in a referent answer, while I was writing this one

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't in the string concatenation, but in the number of commas of the query. Whatever DBMS you use, you don't have to put so many commas, and a ';' in `SELECT min(id)` (that is seen as the end of `SELECT` statement).

For this reason, the DBMS engine doesn't recognize the statement and it prints a syntax error.

Your query, in your C++ program, should look like this:

```
sql = "DELETE from spamtrigrams WHERE id in(" \
    "SELECT id from spamtrigrams " \
    "EXCEPT(SELECT min(id) "  \
    "from spamtrigrams " \
    "group by TRIGRAM " \
    "having count(1) > 1 " \
    "union all " \
    "SELECT min(id) " \
    "from spamtrigrams " \
    "group by TRIGRAM " \
    "having count(1) = 1));";
```

Furthermore, don't forget to add a whitespace between the keywords and the identifiers.

Comment: Need to add whitespace between keywords and identifiers, too.

Comment: Thanks Alberto - I pasted your code into my function but the same error still occurs. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @TheBlueNile I don't know honestly. Before posting the answer, I tested the query and I didn't have any issue, like yours for the brackets. Are you sure that you have still the same syntax error?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Yes, still the same error. I'm going to abandon that function and just make the data in the TRIGRAM column unique, so that future inserts will throw an error if any duplicate values are attempted to be added to the table. Thanks.